# Reverse reading via regex or grabbing last match with no tail

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I need to grab the 2 character letter and numbers after that:

What I want is:

```
AB 12 CD-12345-67   -> CD-12345
AB12 CD 12345-67 ->  CD 12345 
AB-12CD12345-6 ->  CD12345
ABC1234556 -> no match, as I look for 2 character letter and numbers after that.
ABC-1234556 -> no match, as I look for 2 character letter and numbers after that.
A1-BC-12D345-56 -> no match, after 2 characters letter, numbers must come
```

I used this regex

```
 [A-Z]{2}[ |\-]?\d+
```

Which grabs CD-12345 and AB 12, in the first example. I just need CD-12345. Also it grabs BC1234556,BC-1234556, BC-12 in the last three example which i don't want.
Sometimes, space,no space or  - character placed between numbers and letters block.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try [`(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3,6}`](https://regex101.com/r/sY8zY3/1)

Comment: Do you use it in JavaScript (you mentioned that you are using a regexr website to test the regex)? You should add the relevant tag to the question. In JS, use [`(^|[^A-Z])([A-Z]{2}[ -]?[0-9]{3,6})`](https://regex101.com/r/sY8zY3/3) and use  group 2 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on what you posted

```
^.*(?<![A-Z])([A-Z]{2}[- ]?\d++)(?![A-Z])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/386)